# Excel VBA to copy multiple rows and insert to next row depending on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently facing a problem where I am not able to copy and insert the rows correctly after few button clicks. The logic I want to achieve is to copy each rows excluding the header and append to next row. Please refer to the image provided.

[Default Template *Before button click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PisnU.png)

[After inserting from last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIUHF.png)

[Continue to insert normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM9wm.png)

[Eventually will reach to this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7PFx.png)

Below are my codes which is a mess. I am new to VBA, please guide me in this, Thank you.

```
Sub bt_add()

Dim a1 As Integer
Dim a2 As Integer
Dim a3 As Integer
Dim a4 As Integer
Dim a5 As Integer
Dim a6 As Integer
Dim a7 As Integer
Dim a8 As Integer
Dim a9 As Integer
Dim a10 As Integer
Dim a11 As Integer
Dim a12 As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim s As Integer

Static clicked As Integer

a1 = 2
a2 = 3
a3 = 6
a4 = 7
a5 = 10
a6 = 11
a7 = 14
a8 = 15
a9 = 18
a10 = 19
a11 = 22
a12 = 23

n = clicked
s = clicked + 1

If clicked = 0 Then
    a1 = 2
    a2 = 3
    a3 = 6
    a4 = 7
    a5 = 10
    a6 = 11
    a7 = 14
    a8 = 15
    a9 = 18
    a10 = 19
    a11 = 22
    a12 = 23

    clicked = clicked + 1
Else
    If clicked >= 2 Then
        a1 = a1 + n
        a2 = a2 + n
        a3 = a2 * 2
        a4 = a2 * 2 + 1
        a5 = a5 + n + 1 + s
        a6 = a6 + n + 1 + s
        a7 = a7 + n + 3 + s
        a8 = a8 + n + 3 + s
        a9 = a9 + n + 5 + s
        a10 = a10 + n + 5 + s
        a11 = a11 + n + 7 + s
        a12 = a12 + n + 7 + s

        clicked = clicked + 1
    Else
        a1 = a1 + n
        a2 = a2 + n
        a3 = a2 * 2
        a4 = a2 * 2 + 1
        a5 = a5 + n + 2
        a6 = a6 + n + 2
        a7 = a7 + n + 3
        a8 = a8 + n + 3
        a9 = a9 + n + 4
        a10 = a10 + n + 4
        a11 = a11 + n + 5
        a12 = a12 + n + 5

        clicked = clicked + 1
    End If

End If



'MsgBox a1 & ", " & a2 & ", " & a3 & ", " & a4 & ", " & a5 & ", " & a6 & ", " & a7 & ", " & a8 & ", " & a9 & ", " & a10 & ", " & a11 & ", " & a12 & ", " & n & ", " & s

Selection.Copy
Rows(a1).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a2).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(a3).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a4).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(a5).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a6).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(a7).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a8).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(a9).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a10).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Rows(a11).EntireRow.Copy
Rows(a12).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI: Your first variable block has a12 as integer - the rest are variant since the type is undeclared. This is a pretty common mistake amongst beginners - I myself fell in that trap when I first started VBA

Comment: Questions: 1) How do you identify if it's a header? if the text is bold? 2) Everytime you click the button if you're not in a header row, macro will insert a row and duplicate values from previous row in columns A to D (preserving the ones that are formulas)? 3) Is this process for a single line or you want to "generate" the new rows all at once?

Comment: @urdearboy Hey, thanks for pointing out. I've changed it, the result is still the same.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do really. You just want to click one button, and each time it inserts a new row under each headers table? Is that the only criteria? What's going on with the cells you highlighted?

Comment: @RicardoDiaz 
Thanks for the reply,
Q1: You can ignore that one because after the first insert, the number in the variable will increase which will skip the header.
Q2: You have to select the data row and insert to the next row which will ignore the header row.
Q3: I want it to generate all at once if possible, because from my code, It generate one row by another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If*this is what you are looking for*, the macro assumes you will always maintain only one blank row between each subsection. This will copy the last row in each subsection and insert it below while preserving the 1 blank row below before the next table.

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub InsertRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, LR As Long

LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If ws.Range("A" & i) = "" Then
            ws.Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert
            ws.Range("A" & i - 1).EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("A" & i)
        End If
    Next i
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You will also need to format your button to now expand with the rows lol

Comment: @undearboy Thank you very much, this is exactly what I am looking for. My code is so bad.. hahaha